# Failed to forward the packet using xdp. Procedure

Tags: ebpf, xdp-bpf

I wanted to use xdp to forward traffic from 127.0.0.1:9999 on the lo network card to 127.0.0.1:8080 to access the golang web service I started, but the web service never connected.

cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe

bpf_trace_printk: source3879 target 36895

```
//+build ignore
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_endian.h>
#define MAX_CPU 128
#define ETH_P_IP        0x0800

struct pkt_meta {
    union {
        __be32 src;
        __be32 srcv6[4];
    };
    union {
        __be32 dst;
        __be32 dstv6[4];
    };
    __u16 port16[2];
    __u16 l3_proto;
    __u16 l4_proto;
    __u16 data_len;
    __u16 pkt_len;
    __u32 seq;
};

static __always_inline bool parse_tcp(struct tcphdr *tcp,
                      struct pkt_meta *pkt)
{
    pkt->port16[0] = tcp->source;
    pkt->port16[1] = tcp->dest;
    pkt->seq = tcp->seq;
    return true;
}

static __always_inline bool parse_ip4(struct iphdr *iph,
                      struct pkt_meta *pkt)
{
    if (iph->ihl != 5)
        return false;
    pkt->src = iph->saddr;
    pkt->dst = iph->daddr;
    pkt->l4_proto = iph->protocol;
    return true;
}

SEC("xdp")
int process_packet(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    struct tcphdr *tcp;
    struct iphdr *iph;
    struct pkt_meta pkt = {};
    __u32 off;

    /* parse packet for IP Addresses and Ports */
    off = sizeof(struct ethhdr);
    if (data + off > data_end)
        return XDP_PASS;

    pkt.l3_proto = bpf_htons(eth->h_proto);

    if (pkt.l3_proto == ETH_P_IP) {
        iph = data + off;
        if ((void *)(iph + 1) > data_end)
            return false;
        if (!parse_ip4(iph, &pkt))
            return XDP_PASS;
        off += sizeof(struct iphdr);
    }
    if (data + off > data_end)
        return XDP_PASS;

    if (pkt.l4_proto == IPPROTO_TCP) {
        tcp = data + off;
        if ((void *)(tcp + 1) > data_end)
            return false;
        off += sizeof(struct tcphdr);

        if (pkt.port16[1] == bpf_htons(9999) && pkt.dst == bpf_htonl(0x7f000001)) {
            tcp->dest = bpf_htons(8080);
            iph->daddr = bpf_htonl(0x7f000001);
            bpf_printk("source%d target %d\n", pkt.port16[1], tcp->dest);
            return XDP_TX;
        }
    }
    return XDP_PASS;
}
char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

Is there something wrong with my code or with my logic？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of appeal, the client resets the `[syn,ack]` packet on the server when the tcp connection is established, so you also need to change the source port `8080` to `9999` at the client receiving network card to succeed.
example:

```
 if (tcp->source == bpf_htons(8080) && iph->saddr == bpf_htonl(0x7f000001)) {
        tcp->source = bpf_htons(9999);
        iph->saddr = bpf_htonl(0x7f000001);
        return XDP_PASS;
    }
```